# Building a Scanner with an embedded FileReader recursively in java

Tags: java, filereader, java.util.scanner

```
public static Scanner getFileScanner()
{
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file = input.nextLine();
        Scanner fs = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));            
    }catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        System.out.println("Invalid filename. Try another:");
        getFileScanner();
    }finally{
        return fs;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error that the variable fs isn't found. I can't figure out why for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fs` is declared under `try` block... to fix this, declare it outside the block:-

```
Scanner fs = null;
try {
    ...
    fs = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
    ...
}
finally {
    return fs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared inside a `try` block are not in scope inside the corresponding `finally` block. There are a number of issues with your approach in general... it's generally not a good idea to `return` inside a `finally` block, for example.

Here's what I'd do:

```
public static Scanner getFileScanner() {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  File file = null;
  while (true) {
    file = new File(input.nextLine());
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile())
      break;
    System.out.println("Invalid filename. Try another:");
  }
  return new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by listing the problems in your code:

1. The compilation error on the `return` statement is caused by `fs` being out of scope as described in other answers.
2. When you make the recursive call to `getFileScanner()`, you don't assign or return the result.  So it won't make it back to the caller.
3. Using a `return` in a `finally` block is a **bad idea**.  It will squash (throw away) any other exceptions that might be propagating at that point; e.g. exceptions that don't match a `catch` or exceptions thrown in a `catch` block.
4. The `input.nextLine()` call will throw an exception if the underlying stream has reached the EOF; e.g. the user typed [CONTROL]+D or whatever.  You don't *have to* catch it (it is unchecked), but the return in the `finally` block squashes it (probably) resulting in the caller getting a `null` instead.  Ughh ...
5. Hard-wiring `System.in` and `System.out` makes your method less reusable.  (OK, this may not be an issue you should address in this particular case.  And I won't, below ...)
6. In theory, your method could be made to throw a `StackOverflowError`; e.g. if the user hits [ENTER] a number of times.  This problem is inherent in your recursive solution, and is a good reason not to do it that way.

Finally, here's a version of the method that addresses these problems:

```
public static Scanner getFileScanner() throws NoSuchElementException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String file = input.nextLine();
        try {
            return new Scanner(new FileReader(file));           
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("Invalid filename. Try another:");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've replaced the recursion, gotten rid of the `finally`, and declared the exception that is thrown.  (One could catch that exception and either report it, or rethrow it as an application specific exception.)

Answer (score 0):

Declare it first:

```
public static Scanner getFileScanner() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fs = null;
    while(fs == null) {
        try{
            String file = input.nextLine();
            Scanner fs = new Scanner(new File(file));            
        }catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("Invalid filename. Try another:");
        }
    }
    return fs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared fs in the try block and try to access it in a different scope (the finally block). The usual paradigms is to declare fs before the try block as null.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what the other guys indicated with their code samples...

Because you declare the `fs` variable within the `try` block the variable will only be scoped (visible) within the braces immediately after the `try` keyword.

By moving the `fs` variable declaration out of the try block and into the `getFileScanner` method body you are ensuring that the variable can be accessed by all blocks within the method body (`try`, `catch` and `finally` blocks).

Hope that helps!